# Right aligning background color in list item

Tags: html, css, graph

I'm trying to set up a bar graph that plots bars from right to left. On the right hand side of the graph I have a vertical rule, which the bars should touch. But right now the bars are left aligned and I can't figure out how to fix this.

http://jsfiddle.net/7f58a/3/

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <ul class="float-right alignRight">
        <li>Value 1</li>
        <li>Value 2</li>
        <li>Value 3</li>
        <li>Value 4</li>
        <li>Value 5</li>
        <li>Value 6</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="vr float-right"></div>
    <ul class="float-right alignRight">
        <li class="bar rounded-left" style="width: 5px"></li>
        <li class="bar rounded-left" style="width: 5px"></li>
        <li class="bar rounded-left" style="width: 5px"></li>
        <li class="bar rounded-left" style="width: 20px">+1</li>
        <li class="bar rounded-left" style="width: 5px"></li>
        <li class="bar rounded-left" style="width: 5px"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    list-style: none;
}
.rounded, .rounded-right {
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
.rounded, .rounded-left {
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
.vr {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #cea4d8;
    height: 185px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.bar {
    background-color: #cea4d8;
    height: 25px;
}
.box {
    width: 330px;
}
.box li{
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.alignRight {
    text-align: right;
}
.float-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in bar class add floating to right and clear both:

```
.bar {
    background-color: #cea4d8;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

And will work.